# HTTP GET Not Fired for Script Tag with Type application/json

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, mime-types

Making a call to a REST API by adding a `<script>` tag to the DOM. I need to set the type to `application/json` to avoid a JS error.  A JSON object is returned by the API, and using `type=text/javascript` periodically gives a syntax error because the browser is expecting JavaScript but instead reads JSON.  Depending on the browser, it will give an "Unexpected token :" error on the first colon, or "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"property_name":"

This block does not perform the API call: 
(Please note this call requires and auth key, so this code gives a 500 error as written.)

```
<script>
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'application/json';
    s.src = '//my.api.com/api/v2/asset.json';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Using the default "text/javascript" type makes the API call but gives the syntax error:

```
<script>
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '//my.api.com/api/v2/asset.json';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Can I set the MIME type to something else that will fire the API call (HTTP GET)?  or is there something we need to setup on the API so this call will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not know how to execute scripts expressed in JSON (because it isn't a scripting language, it is a data format) so you can't use a `<script>` element to load a JSON file.

Use XMLHttpRequest if you want to load JSON data for use with JavaScript.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you.  I figured there was a simple fundamental aspect of "how browsers work" that I was missing.